# Problemas para editar scripts en Unity usando Visual Studio Code instalados desde Flathub en linux

Tags: c#, linux, unity, unity3d

Un saludo de antemano a todos, verán tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar scripts de C# en Unity con mi VSCode en mi maquina linux Kubuntu, instale Unity con flatpak desde flathub y en si mismo corre bien pero cuando fui a ejecutar un script me decía que debía instalar VSCode desde flathub lo cual hice y de esta manera me abren bien los scripts C# sin embargo parece que no me reconoce los paquetes Dotnet 6 y Mono 6 que ya tengo instalados en mi sistema mandando el siguiente mensaje cada vez que abro un script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Repito que yo ya tengo instalado dotnet 6 y mono 6 en mi sistema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que dice el mensaje del primer capture debo instalar estos mismos packetes (dotnet 6 y mono 6) desde flathub como ya lo hice con VSCode y con el mismo Unity pero hasta ahora no he encontrado la manera de hacer esto.

Incluso el VSCode instalado desde Flathub no me reconoce los packetes haciendo que la extension C# para VSCode arroje la siguiente advertencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo más cercano que he tenido a una solución fue hacer que se abran los scripts con mi VSCode que instale desde la web oficial, con este no me aparecen mensajes de ningún tipo aunque por lo que noto no posee el auto completado de código ni de C# como lenguaje ni de Unity como entorno por lo que puede ser complicado desarrollar código de esta manera (ya tengo instalada la extension de C# en este VSCode).

Mi version de UnityHub es 3.4.1

Solo para aclarar, tengo instalados dos VSCode, uno desde la web oficial en el cual no me surgen mensajes de advertencia de ningún tipo pero no veo que se autocomplete el código ni sugerencias de ningún tipo además de que tuve que hacer que todos los archivos tipo C# se abran por defecto con este VSCode porque en las preferencias de Unity no me dejaba colocarlo como editor externo por defecto lo que hace que solo pueda abrir un script a la vez y no toda la carpeta del proyecto de Unity, por otra parte tengo otro VSCode instalado desde flathub el cual Unity si me deja colocar como editor externo por defecto y abrir el proyecto entero en el editor de código pero es en este en donde dotnet 6 y mono 6 parecen no funcionar. En ambos tengo instalada la extension de VSCode para C#.

Verdaderamente me gustaría empezar en el mundo del desarrollo de videojuegos y por esto me es importante solucionar este problema para tener un entorno optimo. Una vez más gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que es necesario que instales **.NET Core SDK** para que la extensión funcione correctamente.

No es lo mismo que **Mono**, una de las primeras implementaciones de terceros para C# en Linux.

Dale clic al botón de <kbd>Get SDK</kbd> y sigue los pasos.